# how to put cropped image in a black frame of given dimensions

Tags: html, css, xhtml

How to put a cropped image like 150 width 170 height onto a frame/canvas of 200 width px 170 height px kindly tell me now in html. So that every time a image is uploaded it crops itself and if its not of 200px 170px dimensions then automatically from both the sides its canvas goes black for the remaining part

Comment: Casn you show, in a jsfiddle perhaps, what you already have?

Comment: Please add the relevant html to the question...

Comment: i just want a method that on a web page no matter where but a frame to be made through css of inline css where the logic of image can be implement, it is a very simple page like you are making a profile page and you have uploaded your pic from pc and then on next page your pic is displaying just like above on the web page where ever we want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.frame {width:200px; height:170px; overflow:hidden;}

.frame img {width:100%; height:auto;}
```

upd: but bottom part of image will be hidden

Comment: here if the pic in less then 200px and 170px then also no black portion is displayed i want that if image is shorter then the remaining portion be black of the frame

Comment: ok, i understand now, maybe this is what you want -  .frame {width:200px; height:170px; text-align:center; background:#000;}

Comment: Thnx mate it worked :D